# How do i send an array in an email message (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I was wondering how to send an array within an email message. I'm using pre tags to format it in the webpage. But im not able to send any data in the email. Here is the controller that im using:

```
  <?php 


    class Notification extends CI_Controller {


    public function index()
        {


            $this->db->select('product_name,project_code'); 
     $this->db->from('user');
     $this->db->like('product_name', 'Test');   



     $array = $this->db->get()->result();
     $size = count($array); 

     echo 'The number of test are: ';
     echo $size;  
       echo '    ';
    echo "<pre>";
     print_r($array);
     echo "</pre>";

     $config = Array(
                  'protocol' => 'smtp',
                  'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
                  'smtp_port' => 465,
                  'smtp_user' => 'Email',
                  'smtp_pass' => 'Password',
                  'mailtype'  => 'text', 
                  'charset'   => 'iso-8859-1'
                                  );
                    $this->load->library('email', $config);
                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

                    // Set to, from, message, etc.
                     $this->email->from('sender', 'Name');
            $this->email->to('reciever'); 

            $this->email->subject(' Test Updates');

            $this->email->message($array);



               $result = $this->email->send(); 

    }




}

?>
```

I want to send the array $array in the email which is formatted similar to the pre tags. 
[Note: I've edited out the email details. Other email functions work as expected]

Comment: I posted your answer to same question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763899/how-to-format-text-in-codeigniter

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the `message` method takes an array as a parameter. Try

```
$this->email->message(print_r($array, true));
```

Comment: Hey aaron, thanks for the reply. I tried the method that you suggested and it indeed sends the array in the email. Any idea on how it can be formatted using something similar to "pre" tags, so that they can easily read?

Comment: If you're sending an HTML email then surround it in `<pre>` tags. Otherwise you may need to traverse the array and form a more readable string.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative option for you, or anyone else reading this thread.

You can also create a view file for the email, passing the array as data.

In your controller:

```
$data['my_array'] = $array;
$this->email->message($this->load->view('my_email', $data, TRUE));
```

In your **my_email.php** view:

```
<pre><?php print_r($my_array);?></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Has you defined the email receiver ? like you@gmail.com
 For sure what the problem matter you can use

```
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```